# Google Pixel C device UI not changing to landcape mode based on CSS selector

Tags: css, sass

I am working for a hybrid application, and found that "Google Pixel C" device, the UI shown in portrait mode is same as landscape mode though a CSS selector is used for the change.
I am using cordova framework for the development. When the device is in landscape mode I am applying landscape class to the body tag and removing the class, when the device is in portrait mode.

The media query used to show the landscape mode is as shown below:

```
@media screen and (min-width:480px) {
    body.landscape #Login #Logo {
        float: left;
        width: 45%;
        margin: 4% auto;
   }
    body:not(.landscape) #Login #Logo {
        width: 100%;
        margin: 4% auto;
   }
```

}

I also tried using the media query:

```
@media screen and (min-width:480px) and (orientation : portrait) {
  #Login #Logo {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 4% auto;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width:480px) and (orientation : landscape) {
  #Login #Logo {
    float: left;
    width: 45%;
    margin: 4% auto;
   }
}
```

but found that when keyboard is up, the media query of landscape gets applied even though device is in portrait mode.

Is anyone else facing the same problem?? Any suggestion would help.

Answer (score 0):

Found solution to the problem. When there is an orientation change, have started applying landscape class to the body tag and written media queries accordingly